# Check isnull in the field of a row

Tags: codenameone

Is there any method for checking a field value of a row from an SQLite table that has a null value?
There are methods of the row like getInteger, getString,..... but no method for checking null value.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your programming platform, but can you just put WHERE `column` IS NULL in your sql statement?

Comment: I solve this problem. Database.wasNull to check if the last value accessed from a given row was null.

Comment: I see that we had something similar here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/db/Row.java#L114
Notice you can use `getString() == null` or `getBlob() == null` which should work.